# Save data from broken Macbook Pro HDD

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, partition, hdd

I have a broken Macbook Pro HDD with two partitions on it: OS X and Bootcamp. I need to take some files from both partitions:

- the HDD is now mounted to another PC via. SATA adapter
- Windows sees the HDD but i can't access it. For example, I can't format it
- With gparted, it says that there's no filesystem, nor allocated space
- I tried CloneZilla, but since there's no filesystem, it can't copy anything
- I tried testdisk and photorec without luck
- I tried fdisk and superbloack options with Linux without luck

Now, I don't know if I have to format it and try to recover the files I need, is there a way to repair?

Comment: You might need to install some app to make windows be able to read and write Mac OS X format. Once you have done that, would it be possible to fix the mac's boot? Or is the damage more extensive?

Answer (score 2):

1. you can try to connect you HDD to another mac.
2. you can create full copy of this disk via dd vith [noerror parameter](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/dd.htm)
3. If you use windows you cat use [Ext2Read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/) for access to linux partition.

Comment: 1. yeah i still have to try this option
2. how i it ?
3. the bootcamp partition has windows installed, i´m trying to use linux to access it

Comment: 1. ok 2. you can connect two disk to linux PC: broken disk and new disk, and clone broken disk to new: [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_cloning).

Comment: if you do not break the partition table, you connect the new drive into the notebook and everything will work.